# Spring sleuth zipkin spans not nesting in Kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth, kotlinx.coroutines

I can see spans being recorded in the Zipkin UI from the following Spring Boot controller code:

```
@RestController
class ConcurrentController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var restTemplate : RestTemplate
    val urls = arrayListOf<String>("http://www.google.com","http://www.facebook.com")
    private val logger = Logger.getLogger(this::class.java.getName())
    @RequestMapping("/concurrent1")
    fun endPoint1() : String {
        logger.info("/concurrent1")
        var s = ""
        runBlocking {
            val a = urls.map { url ->
                logger.info(url)
                async(CommonPool) {
                logger.info("getting $url")
                restTemplate.getForObject(url, String::class.java)
                sleep(5000)
                logger.info("got $url")
                }
            }
            val b = a.map { it.await() }
            s = b.joinToString { "" }
        }
        return s
    }
}
```

and the log output looks like:

```
2017-10-30 20:56:04.525  INFO [coroutinesDemo,eb6fd4fedb6f3a6d,eb6fd4fedb6f3a6d,true] 13547 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : /concurrent1
2017-10-30 20:56:04.543  INFO [coroutinesDemo,eb6fd4fedb6f3a6d,eb6fd4fedb6f3a6d,true] 13547 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : http://www.google.com
2017-10-30 20:56:04.548  INFO [coroutinesDemo,eb6fd4fedb6f3a6d,eb6fd4fedb6f3a6d,true] 13547 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : http://www.facebook.com
2017-10-30 20:56:04.548  INFO [coroutinesDemo,,,] 13547 --- [onPool-worker-9] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : getting http://www.google.com
2017-10-30 20:56:04.549  INFO [coroutinesDemo,,,] 13547 --- [onPool-worker-2] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : getting http://www.facebook.com
2017-10-30 20:56:09.703  INFO [coroutinesDemo,,,] 13547 --- [onPool-worker-2] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : got http://www.facebook.com
2017-10-30 20:56:09.703  INFO [coroutinesDemo,,,] 13547 --- [onPool-worker-9] c.e.coroutines.ConcurrentController      : got http://www.google.com
```

but the traces are independent in the UI.

I would expect the two calls to Google and Facebook urls to be nested concurrently under the call to the `/concurrent1` endpoint.

I suspect that it's due to the thread that coroutines are executed on being different to the one in which the spring application is started but I have no idea how to move forward with Spring Sleuth at this point!

Comment: I guess it's related to `async(CommonPool) {...}`. I don't know kotlin so I don't really know what it does. But if you run stuff in an asynchronous mode you have to ensure that you pass the tracing context.

Comment: A defect exists for this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1737

Answer (score 2):

***Attention: This solution does works for logging purposes, but does not work for other Sleuth features like instrumenting RestTemplates to send the tracing headers to other services. So unfortunately, this is not a fully working solution. :(***

Some time after adopting @Baca's solution, I discovered that Kotlin Coroutines offer direct integration with slf4j, which is what Spring Sleuth builds on.
Sleuth adds properties `X-B3-TraceId`, `traceId`, `X-B3-SpanId`, and `spanId` to the thread's MDC.

You can retain the parent thread's MDC for a coroutine with the code shown below. The coroutine framework will take care of restoring the MDC context on the worker thread whenever the coroutine is executed/resumed. This is the easiest solution I could discover so far. :)

```kotlin
// add your own properties or use the ones already added by Sleuth
MDC.put("someLoggerProperty", "someValue")

GlobalScope.launch(MDCContext()) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

The launch method takes an optional CoroutineContext and the coroutine-slf4j integration implements the MDCContext. This class captures the calling thread's MDC context (creates a copy) and uses that for the coroutine execution.

Add this dependency to your build.gradle:

```
implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j', version: '1.3.9'
```

Project: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j
Documentation: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I use "TraceCallable" class from "[spring-cloud-sleuth](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-core)" lib to solve it in my code.

My code example is:

```kotlin
@Component
class TracingCallableSupplier(
    private val tracing: Tracing,
    private val spanNamer: SpanNamer
) {

    /**
     * Supply callable which will use tracing from parent while performing jobs.
     */
    fun <T : Any?> supply(function: () -> T): Callable<T> {
        return TraceCallable(tracing, spanNamer, Callable(function))
    }
}

@Service
class MyBean{
    @Autowired
    lateinit var traceSupplier : TracingCallableSupplier

    fun myMethod {
        val callable = tracingCallableSupplier.supply {
            // ... some code to be called asynchronous...
        }

        // simplest coroutine...
        GlobalScope.launch {
            callable.call()
        }

        // more advanced coroutine usage...
        val deferred = (0 until 10).map {
            async {
                callable.call()
            }
        }

        runBlocking {
            deferred.map {
                val result = it.await()
                // ... some processing ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```